# What happens to non-serialized objects in memory?

Tags: java, oop, object, serialization, deserialization

Now I know the basic definition of serialization and all. The book definition is that it is converted to byte stream and all. But I want to now the internal working details of this serialization. That is How non serialized object is represented in memory vs how serialized ones are represented, and how does the non serialized one face problem while being converted to byte stream.

Comment: I may be wrong but it seems to be an off-topic question for SO being more appropriate for [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/72102/understanding-serialization)

Comment: @AlexRudenko why is it off topic for SO? There are so many CS QnA over here.

Comment: according to the [on-topic list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) this question seems to fall into the following category: 5. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.